# CSS sprite image height issue

Tags: css

I am trying to place an image using png css sprite which i created from website http://css.spritegen.com. The problem is image container is expanding up very much in firefox and IE browsers but working fine in Chrome. 
The below styles have been applied

```
    background: url('https://coinswitch-static-resource-dev.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ui/public/images/cspro-sprite.png') no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    text-align: left;
    background-position: -10px -0px;
    width: 996px;
    height: 996px;
    zoom: 0.03;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.03);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Here's a demo url https://codepen.io/amitasaurus/pen/QWWYgXW .

Comment: you no more need to use `-moz-`

Comment: in which part ? @TemaniAfif

Comment: everywhere, all the `-moz-` in your code are useless and are probably causing the issue